# How can you go from IE 8.0.7600.16385 to IE 8.0.7601.17514 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, upgrade, updates, internet-explorer-8

Simple question:  How can you upgrade Internet explorer from version 8.0.7600.16385 to version 8.0.7601.17514 on Windows 7?  There doesn't seem to be much of an "Update button" anywhere on IE for this sort of thing, installation downloads for IE8 from Microsoft just say that Windows 7 doesn't support IE8 when you try to run them, and it's pretty heavily tied in with the operating system itself.  Any ideas?

Part of the context here is that we're really trying to do this as surgically as we reasonably can, without putting much else on the computer or anything.

Comment: Have you installed all available updates through Windows Update?  Because the update in question should be installed as a security update.

Comment: Worth noting that most sites just support the latest or last two major revisions of browsers. Now that IE11 is out, that means IE10 and 11. If you are wanting this ancient version for testing purposes, you may want to argue for dropping support. Obviously this is often not reasonable, though.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but we're having to integrate a bunch of different things together, and a lot of this is over a LAN.  Since this computer is used for very specific reasons over that LAN, we're trying to alter it as little as possible.  If that version of IE could be pinpointed to one particular Windows update though, we probably wouldn't have to get special permission or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implied by this page [ie binarydb](http://binarydb.com/soft/Internet-Explorer-v1703.html) this version of IE8 is installed with windows 7 SP1.
Since 7SP1 is supposed to be a collection of KB fixes, perhaps you can search the installed KB in that Win7's windows directories for this version number (in the contents of one of the text files) to isolate the KB and then search MS for that KB? I suspect that won't be publicly available.

But if the goal is to duplicate the environment, maybe upgrading to sp1 is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks.  I've had to sidetrack on a different subset of the issue for now, but I'll look a little more into your answer when I get a chance.